# How to use SQLite as testing database in EF Core for ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, testing, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, sqlite-net

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that uses EF core and my SQL for its persistence layer. So I want to test my Web API project using XUnit. But, I would like to use SQLite in-memory database to avoid all efforts to create a fresh database for each test.

So, I have migration C# files those are created based on MySQL but I want to apply them to my SQLite version 3 database.

I am using this code to apply all structures on my database at the start point of the application:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>();

        if (dbContext.Database.IsRelational() && dbContext.Database.GetMigrations().Any())
        {
            await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using this code to replace the MySQL database with SQLite inside my using `IClassFixture`:

```
 UnregisterDependency<DbContextOptions<BordarVmsDbContext>>(services);
 UnregisterDependency<DbConnection>(services);
        
 var connectionString = "DataSource=testDB;mode=memory;cache=shared;";
 var keepAliveConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
    
 keepAliveConnection.Open();
        
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>( options =>
 {
      options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
      Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new GuidHandler());
      options.UseSqlite(keepAliveConnection); 
 });
```

But I get this error raised when I run my application:

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such collation sequence: ascii_general_ci'.

How can I use SQLite as my temporary database in testing environment?

Comment: Start by not expecting that SQL written against MySQL, will work with SQLite.

Comment: You will change the connection string, 
Importing table structures, SP and Views from mysql into SQLite. Some limitation, will be occured here. The data types also maybe different between SQLite and Mysql. 

After that, you maybe need to re-import DBContext,  scaffold it, and fixing if any errors happened. 

This is the way as I know maybe another user have some alternatives.